# Are 2 powerheads too strong?

Tags: aquarium

I using 2 AquaClear 30 powerheads with my Lee's 30 gallon under gravel filter. Both are set at the lowest flow possible. Are they still too strong?

Comment: It really depend on the type of fish/plants you have in there.

Comment: Good point! Researching the subject I find the # of fish/plants in the tank have a lot to do with the answer I'm looking for. Thank you.